# How do I know if our emails are being marked as Spam?

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, spam

We host our site on Amazon EC2. Our users subscribe for weekly email alerts. Since many IPs with EC2 are with a history, to make sure mails are not marked as spam, we use a third party SMTP service. Recently, Amazon has also set up reverse DNS entry for us. We haven't received any abuse notice so far.

I receive couple of these emails on my personal gmail account and those are not marked as spam. How do I know if any of our emails are being marked as spam?

Comment: You're already monitoring the receipt at a personal gmail account. Just as a sanity check, you could also set up hotmail and yahoo accounts just in case their spam filtering criteria is slightly different.

Comment: @btreat, Good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check with your SMTP service to see if they process their SMTP logs looking for whether your mail was received or not.  Many times, there are helpful clues about whether the recipient domain accepted the mail or not.

Additionally, you should set up a SPF record, especially if your SMTP service is sending mail from a different domain and/or IP.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: I have come across suggestions of SPF and your answer reinforces the same.